# How to determine the number of columns and rows in a matrix?

Tags: matrix, code-request

Let A and B be two matrices (not necessarily square matrices).  How can I determine if the number of columns in matrix A are the same as the number of rows in matrix B?

Comment: Use `Dimensions[mat, 2]` to get `{rowLen, columnLen}` down to `Level 2`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is there a function that gives me information strictly on the number of columns and another function that gives me information strictly on the number of rows?

Comment: To get only `row length` you can use `Length[mat]`, and to get `column length` (assuming all row elements have equal length) use `Length[mat[[1]]]`.

Comment: Thank you very much I'm just learning Mathematica and this is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
A = Table[1, {5}, {3}];
B =  Table[1, {7}, {5}];
Dimensions[A][[1]] == Dimensions[B][[2]]
```

(* True *)

Comment: Awesome thanks so much!  This worked for me!