# How to determine the number of columns and rows in a matrix, whose all rows do not have equal number of columns?

Tags: list-manipulation

I know this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137429/54258).
If there are an equal number of columns on each row, then
Number of rows: $Length[[MatrixName]]$
and number of columns: $Length[MatrixName[[1]]]$.
However, I have a big dataset whose each row does not have an equal number of columns. How can I  find the number of rows of a particular column or the number of columns for a particular row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1234];

(mat = Take[#, RandomInteger[{3, 5}]] & /@ 
    Array[a, {10, 10}]) // Column
```

[image]

```
nbrCol[mat_, row_Integer?Positive] := Length@mat[[row]]

nbrCol[mat, #] & /@ Range[10]

(* {5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5} *)

nbrRows[mat_, col_Integer?Positive] := 
 Count[mat, _?(Length[#] >= col &)]

nbrRows[mat, #] & /@ Range[10]

(* {10, 10, 10, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.